# Are there any tricks for hard coding units into record fields without losing pretty printing?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am looking to hard code units into my record fields. Currently I have the ToString() method overriden and used the [StructuredFormatDisplay("{AsString}")] atribute. This has worked except for it is unfortunate that I lose FSharp's pretty printing (mainly the offsetting) on types that this record is nested into. With that said, I am wondering if anyone knows of any tricks to accomplish this.

Essentially I have this type:

```
type SteelMaterial =
    {Fy : float<ksi>;
     Fu : float<ksi>;
     E : float<ksi>;}
```

and want it to print out like this:

```
SteelMaterial = {Fy = 50.0 <ksi>;
                 Fu = 60.0 <ksi>;
                 E = 29000.0 <ksi>;}
```

and like this, when nested :

```
Section = {Section = "Section 1";
           Material = {Fy = 50.0 <ksi>;
                       Fu = 60.0 <ksi>;
                       E = 29000.0 <ksi>;};
           Transformations = null;}
```

The reason I am looking to do this is so to document units when producing calculations via F# Formatting (via (*** include-value: mySection **)), Ifsharp or Azure Notebooks.

#### UPDATE

I didn't originally include my implementation since I didn't think it added clarity to the question. Here it is if anyone is wondering.

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{AsString}")>]
type SteelMaterial =
    {
    Fy : float<ksi>
    Fu : float<ksi>
    E : float<ksi>
    }   
    
    static member create (Fy, Fu, E) =
        {Fy = Fy; Fu = Fu; E = E}

    override this.ToString() = 
        sprintf "Steel Material =\r\n{Fy = %f <ksi>;\r\nFu = %f <ksi>;\r\nE = %f <ksi>;}"
            this.Fy this.Fu this.E

    member this.AsString = this.ToString()
```

Comment: The code you post is not [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which makes it hard for people to offer advice. In particular, how do you implement `ToString` that preserves units of measure?

Comment: In general, I'd think you're fighting a losing battle here with how units are erased during compilation and how the pretty printer in question uses runtime reflection to do its work.

Comment: Sorry if this seems incomplete, but ultimately, I didnt include my implementation of the ToString() method since I thought it cluttered the question too much to be clear and minimal. And, as for your question on preserving the units of measure... I didnt. I simply hard coded the string "<ksi>" into the ToString() method. i.e. override this.ToString() = sprintf "{Fy = %f <ksi>;\r\nFu=%f <ksi>;\r\nE = %f <ksi>}" this.Fy this.Fu this.E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can get what I am looking for by wrapping the unit in a DU and overriding that ToString() method.

```
[<Measure>] type ksi

[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{AsString}")>]
type Ksi =
    | Ksi of float<ksi>

    override this.ToString() =
        match this with
        | Ksi value -> System.String.Format("{0:0.0####} <ksi>", value)

    member this.AsString = this.ToString()

    member this.ksi =
        match this with
        | Ksi value -> value


type SteelMaterial =
    {Fy : Ksi;
     Fu : Ksi;
     E : Ksi;}

let mySteelMaterial =
    {Fy = Ksi(50.0<ksi>);
     Fu = Ksi(60.0<ksi>);
     E = Ksi(29000.0<ksi>)}
```

This has some benefits including being able to pattern match on the Ksi type and printing the units as I was looking for. The downside is the cons that come with wrapping values in a DU, which includes the user needing to type `Ksi(10.0<ksi>)` which is not too succinct, and then needing to access the value via the ".ksi".